# convert date format to YYYY-MM-DD of raddatepicker value

Tags: c#, datetime, telerik, raddatepicker

I am trying to convert the value of raddatepicker to YYYY-MM-DD format. But I am getting exception,

```
orderDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;   // Date = {15/7/2015 12:00:00 AM}
string orderDate_ = orderDate.SelectedDate.Value..ToShortDateString();  // 15/7/2015

IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(orderDate_, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture);  // geting exception [System.FormatException] = {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}
```

Getting exception

```
[System.FormatException] = {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}
```

Please suggest how to convert the date format to yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: have you try to use  `yyyy-MMM-dd` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the correct format, you need `dd-MM-yyyy` instead of `yyyy-M-dd`, you can find more in this article [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(orderDate_, "dd-M-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what in case of months greater than 9? I mean for October, November & December

Comment: The format string "M" is for 1-12, it is mentioned in the link I have in my answer, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since `orderDate_` looks `15/7/2015`, you need to use `dd/M/yyyy` format instead.

```
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(orderDate_, "dd/M/yyyy", culture);
```

But I think this is unnecessary because your `orderDate.SelectedDate` is *already* a `DateTime.`

Comment: what in case of months greater than 9? I mean for October, November & December

Comment: @user4221591 [`M` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#M_Specifier) accept `1` to `12`. That means it's fine.